# Cursor Resize on scroll bar of div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The Html div with cursor resize and scroll auto:

```css
.scrollable {
  cursor: ew-resize;
  border-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
  <h1>My First CSS Example</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

The div is displaying the cursor with resize option. But when the scroll bar is visible, the resize cursor is showing inside the scroll bar. How to show the resize cursor outside border of vertical scroll bar.

I have tried using with no luck:

```
.scrollable { 
  cursor: ew-resize; 
}
```

Please provide your suggestions. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Can you post an image that outlines your problem? Also, your css is targeting the "scrollable" class, however your code does not have anything with that class

Comment: posted the image, Thanks

Comment: Can you clean your monitor and post an image that outlines your problem?

Comment: here is the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/69bfszdt/

Comment: My browser (Google Chrome) shows the resize cursor only inside the div content, neither in the padding nor on the scrollbar. Which browser do you use?

Comment: I am using chrome. For me also, cursor is showing inside, but I want outside the scroll bar

Comment: I think the question isn't clear, where do you want the cursor to be applied to? is it **outside of** or **on** the scrollbar? if it's outside, can't you just put the cursor style to the parent?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it might be the padding that's preventing the cursor to stay as it is.

Comment: Damzaky: Yes, outside the scrollbar

Comment: Testing this with FireFox, there is no issue. When the mouse is over the scroll bar, the cursor reverts to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following changes.

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.myDiv {
  cursor: ew-resize;
  border-color: red;
  width: calc(100% - 5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="myDiv">
    <h1>My First CSS Example</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <h1>My First CSS Example</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <h1>My First CSS Example</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is really only needed for Chrome yet does work for other browsers.

The trick here is wrapping your content div and making it sort of a viewport. Now you can adjust the `width` so that when the User moves it over to the scrollbar, the cursor changes back before the very edge.

The issue I saw was that when the cursor box was just a pixel before half, the graphic of the resize cursor still showed and appeared to bleed over onto the scrollbar. This is due to the border of the div element being right at the edge of the window. We can move that border by making the div a bit smaller, yet keeping the scrollbar in the same position, the cursor changes well beforehand and the graphic no longer looks like it bleeds over.

Comment: This seems to just do the exact same thing that Billy's does. It just has a responsive width instead of static.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to display the resize cursor outside the border of the vertical scroll bar as it is determined by the browser's default behavior. You can try changing the border color to transparent or a color that matches the background to make it less noticeable, but the cursor will still be displayed within the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, your problem is more OS or Browser related. I tried to reproduce this from iOS + Chrome and I didn't succeed, everything works as expected for me.
[image]

However for webkit based browsers you can try:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is specifically what you're asking for. I couldn't tell if your goal was to allow the box to resize or not. If my understanding is correct, your goal *is* to allow resize, but you don't want that to interfere with the scrollbar. Here is my best answer based on this:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector("#parent"),
      handle = parent.querySelector("#handle")

let startX,
    startWidth
      
handle.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
  startX = e.clientX
  startWidth = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(parent).width, 10)
  document.documentElement.addEventListener("mousemove", resize, false)
  document.documentElement.addEventListener("mouseup", stopResize, false)
})

function resize(e) {
  parent.style.width = (startWidth + e.clientX - startX) + "px"
}

function stopResize() {
  document.documentElement.removeEventListener("mousemove", resize, false)
  document.documentElement.removeEventListener("mouseup", stopResize, false)
}
```

```css
#parent {
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 300px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  position:relative;
}

#handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -5px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: ew-resize;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">

  <div>
  
    <h1>My First CSS Example</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  
  </div>
  
  <div id="handle">&nbsp;</div>

</div>
```

I restructured the `HTML` `style` attribute into separate `CSS`. First of all, if you want to be able to resize using the right edge of the element, rather than using the built in resize `CSS` (with default `CSS`, use `resize: horizontal;` on the parent), then you will need to us `JavaScript`.

This also requires an additional element to represent the resize bar (`<div id="handle">`). This is where we apply the `cursor: ew-resize;`. Make sure the `position` of the handle is `absolute`, and is placed slightly further right than the parent. It's also important to note, the parent needs to have a `position` of `relative` on it, so that the handle is contained to the parent.

As an explanation of the `JavaScript`, we start by defining our element variables, and presetting the `startX` and `startWidth` variables to undefined, to be redefined later. Next we add an event listener to the handle, to handle the resizing on `mousedown`. This will set the `startX` to the `clientX` position of the handle. Then we set the `startWidth` based on the computed width of the parent, using `parseInt` to convert the string value to a number. Then we handle the `mousemove` and `mouse` in order.

On `mousemove`, we run the `resize` function. This sets the width of `parent` to a pixel value based on the `startWidth`, mouse x position, and starting mouse x position.

On `mouseup` we run the `stopResize` function, which disables the event listeners for `mousemove` and `mouseup`.

Hopefully this is the answer you were looking for. Please let me know if you have any questions, or better explanation for what you were asking for specifically, so I can provide further insight.

Answer (score -1):

Simply wrap your scrollable div with one that has `cursor: ew-resize;`

Comment: This isn't particularly useful. Can you provide some more explanation as to how this solves the issue?

Comment: well, if the resizable div doesnt care or know if its child is scrollable, the cursor will surely be at the border of itself regardless of it’s content, often the solution with css is to create another wrapper rather than trying to do too much at one level, in this case making it scrollable AND resizable